# Where contentOffset comes from?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

i am trying to understand a skillsets in Azure Cognitive Search. I want to build an Ocr powered search and i try to understend how it works.

For example [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-ocr) says taht `ocr skill` produces response:

```
{
  "text": "Hello World. -John",
  "layoutText":
  {
    "language" : "en",
    "text" : "Hello World. -John",
    "lines" : [
      {
        "boundingBox":
        [ {"x":10, "y":10}, {"x":50, "y":10}, {"x":50, "y":30},{"x":10, "y":30}],
        "text":"Hello World."
      },
      {
        "boundingBox": [ {"x":110, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":30},{"x":110, "y":30}],
        "text":"-John"
      }
    ],
    "words": [
      {
        "boundingBox": [ {"x":110, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":30},{"x":110, "y":30}],
        "text":"Hello"
      },
      {
        "boundingBox": [ {"x":110, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":30},{"x":110, "y":30}],
        "text":"World."
      },
      {
        "boundingBox": [ {"x":110, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":30},{"x":110, "y":30}],
        "text":"-John"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[but then in this paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-ocr#sample-merging-text-extracted-from-embedded-images-with-the-content-of-the-document) we see, that only `text` field from OCR skill is used and newcomer, `contentOffset` is presented.

Custom skillset definition:

```
{
  "description": "Extract text from images and merge with content text to produce merged_text",
  "skills":
  [
    {
      "description": "Extract text (plain and structured) from image.",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
      "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "detectOrientation": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "image",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
      "description": "Create merged_text, which includes all the textual representation of each image inserted at the right location in the content field.",
      "context": "/document",
      "insertPreTag": " ",
      "insertPostTag": " ",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name":"text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
          "name": "itemsToInsert", 
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text"
        },
        {
          "name":"offsets", 
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/contentOffset"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "mergedText", 
          "targetName" : "merged_text"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and input should look like this:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "recordId": "1",
      "data":
      {
        "text": "The brown fox jumps over the dog",
        "itemsToInsert": ["quick", "lazy"],
        "offsets": [3, 28]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So how the array of `offsets` (`contentOffset` in skill definition) are coming from where `OcrSkill` response not returning that and `Read` method from computer vision not returning that as well from API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**contentOffset** - is the default feature to extract content from the files are having images embedded init. So, whenever the OCR skillset recognizes images included in the input document, `contentOffset` is called.

To answer the reason for coming array of contentOffset is due to having multiple images in every input we are uploading for analyzing. Consider the following documentation for [ReadAPI through REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-python) to follow the JSON operations.

Comment: Yup that is clear to me, but how to produce `contentOffset` manually? It looks like it not coming from `Read API` but it is produced by `OCR Skill` from custom skillsets.

Comment: Yes, it will be automatically generated by OCR skill. Creating contentOffset manually is a complex thought and error creator. Suggestable to avoid it.